# Speeding up a Django query for "latest" ForeignKey related object

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

With Django, I have two related models. Call the first one `BaseObject`. The second one is called `BaseObjectObservation`, where every 6 hours or so I create a new `BaseObjectObservation` that's linked via ForeignKey to a `BaseObject` and has another field for a particular data point about that object at that time, along with a timestamp.

As you might expect, one thing I'm always interested in is the "latest" `BaseObjectObservation` for a given `BaseObject`. The trouble is that there are now lots of observations for each `BaseObject`, and even with ~500 `BaseObject`s, loading a page with all `BaseObject`s with each one's latest observation gets very slow.

Any recommendations on how to speed up the retrieval of the latest observation?

Bonus question: I'm also interested in how each object's observation has changed over the last 24 hours. Previously I tried querying for the latest observation and the observation closest to 24 hours ago and calculating the difference; this was too slow as well. Any recommendations here?

Comment: "gets very slow" can you be more specific? 5secs, 30secs, 2mins? Do you have indexes in your database? Do you need to load all observations on one page (maybe it makes sense to paginate)? Are you running your app in the cloud or on dedicated server? What are parameters of this server (RAM, CPU)? What database are you using with Django? Have you tried to profile your app? Does it show that loading from database is a bottleneck?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your bonus question. Can you rephrase it please ?

Comment: Yaroslav: I have about 500 BaseObjects, and my home page loads all 500 and tries to get the latest observation for each. The home page is taking ~15-20 sec to load right now. I'm using Heroku with ClearDB, so that's very likely part of the reason, but I'm wondering if there are any potential ways to optimize with what Django offers. No indexes on my databases yet.

Comment: Eliot: let's say BaseObject A has observations A1, A2, A3, ... all spaced 6 hours apart. For the bonus question, I'm interested in taking the most recent observation for A and the observation from 24 hours ago for A, and calculating the difference (to calculate a "velocity" of how much the observation changed). The query for the observation "closest to 24 hours ago" probably takes a long time

Comment: How are you doing this now?  Are you using `latest()`? Have you done any profiling to see how many queries the page load is doing?  Which query is taking the longest? What is the code executing that query?

Comment: No, ClearDB shouldn't be the reason. However Heroku can if you're using free instance (it has very poor performance). Generally you should try to [profile](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.org/en/1.3.2/) your application to identify bottlenecks. @EliotBerriot's answer points in the right direction. Most likely your application uses something like 1 (load all base objects) + 500 (load last observations for every object in a separate query). It should be optimized to 1-2 queries, which will greatly decrease loading time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
class BaseObject(models.Model):
    pass

class BaseObjectObservation(models.Model):
    base_object = models.ForeignKey(BaseObject, related_name="observations")
    last_modification = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    latest = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, **kwargs)

        if not self.pk:
            # mark new instance as latest
            self.latest = True

            # Update previous observations
            self.base_object.observations.update(latest=False)

        super().save(**kwargs)
```

Then, if you want to get latest observations with their base object, you can do :

```
BaseObjectObservation.objects.filter(latest=True).select_related('base_object')
```

The `select_related` clause will save you 500 queries, because it will fetch the base object, along the observation.

Since you do everything in a single query, performance should be better. However, some cleanest solutions may exist without needing to store a boolean on each instance.

## Bonus

For your bonus question, you can probably get [some inspiration here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855715/filter-on-datetime-closest-to-the-given-datetime):

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

24_hours_ago = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=24)


current_observation = base_object.observations.get(latest=True)

closest_observation_greater = base_object.observations.filter(creation_date__gt=24_hours_ago).first()
closest_observation_lower = base_object.observations.filter(creation_date__lte=24_hours_ago).first()

if closest_observation_greater - target > target - closest_observation_lower:
    return closest_observation_lower
else:
    return closest_observation_greater
```

However, that's still two query for each observation. You can probably optimize it, but you can also reduce
the number of element you display on each page. Do you really need to display 500 elements on the same page ?

Comment: I would say 500 queries. Because by default Django will issue separate query for each related field.

Comment: No it won't, because the snippet uses [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: Sorry, it was related to "The select_related clause will save you a query". It will save not a query, but 500 queries.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! It massively reduced the number of queries.

For the bonus, I ended up creating a OneToOne model to BaseObject, where I store the most updated 24 hour calculation. This way it doesn't need to be done when a user visits the page.

Comment: Glad it helps :) For the second part (24H calculation) you can also try [built-in django cache mechanisms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/cache/#basic-usage). It's lighter than building a model to store temporary data, and you'll get better performance ;)